Returning None not breaking out of function
@staticmethod
    def log_in():

        logged_in = False

        while not logged_in:
            username = input("Username: ")

            if not(User.user_exists(username)):
                if input("User not found. Would you like to create an account (y/n)?").lower() != "y" :
                    return None

                User.sign_up(username)


            password = input("Password: ")


            for user in User.users:
                if user["username"] == username:
                    if user["password"] == password:
                        print("Login successful")
                        logged_in = True
                        break

                    else:
                        print("Invalid username or password")

            if logged_in:
                return None

            
            if input("Try again? (y/n): ").lower() != "y":
                break


Even though it's returning None, its running code Would you like to create an account?
(y/n)
Shouldn't it just break out of the functions? Why is it running the code again.

Can you please share a [mcve]?

@Mureinik sorry what I'm not a very experienced programming, have only just started learning. Could you explain what you mean?

Think of it this way: you are asking why the code is running again, but you have not shown us what causes the code to run in the first place. How do we know that your code that calls log_in doesn't call it again? How do we know what User.sign_up does? Basically you've omitted most of the code here. Click the link about [mre] and read what it says. Think about how to construct a minimal reproducible example and take the time and effort to do that.
